# Javascript: How can I loop through a multi-digit number and find the consecutive digit ^ n of each?

Tags: javascript

For instance, let's say I have the number 345. How can I in javascript loop through each digit in the number and raise it to the consecutive nth power: i.e. 3^1 + 4^2 + 5^3?

Comment: Did you try something to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This converts the number to a string splits it into digits then raises each to the power of its index plus one and then reduces via addition to result in the answer:

```
('' + 345).split('').map(function(v, i) {
  return Math.pow(parseInt(v), i+1)
}).reduce(function(a, v) {
  return a + v
}, 0)
```

results in `144`

Answer (score 7):

To calculate the sum using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and  [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let x = String(345).split('').reduce((a, v, i) => a + Math.pow(v, i + 1), 0);

console.log(x); // 144
```

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/path) if, instead of calculating the sum, you want to get the consecutive powers as an array:

```js
let a = String(345).split('').map((v, i) => Math.pow(v, i + 1));

console.log(a); // [3, 16, 125]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using for() loop

```js
"use strict";

let number = 345;
let str = number.toString();
let answer = 0;

for (let i in str) answer += Math.pow(str[i], Number(i)+1);

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
    var number = 345;
    var strNum = number.toString();
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < strNum.length; i++ ){
        sum += Math.pow(parseFloat(strNum[i]), i+1);
    }
    console.log(sum);
</script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Why would you repeatedly call `strNum.substring(...)` rather than just accessing the individual characters with `strNum[i]`?

Comment: That is also a solution, I just developed a logic that came to my mind.